# ¿Como puedo validar mis datos con un esquema desde una ruta en express js?

Tags: nodejs, express

Buen dia tengo mis rutas para agregar,editar y funcionan bien pero ahora quisiera validar los datos que se ingresan por ejemplo si no pusiera el Name que me mandara un mensaje de que ese campo es requerido, estuve viendo unas opciones y me encontre con yup, cree el esquema pero a la hora de correr el codigo y no ingresar el Name en lugar de aprecer el mansaje de que el campo es requerido me arroja SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 131, ¿De que manera puedo mandar llamar mi esquema desde mi ruta para que valide los datos?

Datos

```
{
    "Name": ' ', 
    "Age":17, 
       "Adress":"Los Alamos 232-12",
    "Phone":552685206
}
```

ruta

```
router.post('/apirest/Usuario/Agregar', async(req, res, next) => {
      const { Name, Age, Address, Phone } = req.body;
      let result = await pool1.request()
      .input('Name', sql.VarChar(35), Name)
      .input('Age', sql.Int, Age)
      .input('Address', sql.VarChar(100), Address)
      .input('Phone', sql.VarChar(10), Phone)
      .execute('AgregarUsuario')
      res.redirect('/apirest/Usuarios');
    });
```

esquema

```
 function UsuarioValididation(data){
    const schema=yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required(),
      age: yup
        .number()
        .required()
        .positive()
        .integer(),
         phone: yup
        .number()
        .required()
        .positive()
        .integer(),,
    });
    schema.validateSync(data);
    }

    module.exports={
    UsuarioValididation
    };
```

Comment: otra libreria muy buena es joi https://hapi.dev/family/joi/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edito respuesta segun los comentarios que me hemos tenido.

Seria importar tu librería validador de esquema. (desconozco como lo estas invocando desde express o si lo estas haciendo directamente con node)

```
const validSchema = require('./validador-esquema.js')

router.post('/apirest/Usuario/Agregar', async(req, res, next) => {
      validations.createTiempoRutaValidation
      const { Name, Age, Address, Phone } = req.body;
      //segun la documentacion validateSync regresara throw error cambialo mejor
      // a validate  y usa await
      let isValid = await validSchema.UsuarioValididation(req.body))
      if(isValid.errors) {
        let result = await pool1.request()
      .input('Name', sql.VarChar(35), Name)
      .input('Age', sql.Int, Age)
      .input('Address', sql.VarChar(100), Address)
      .input('Phone', sql.VarChar(10), Phone)
      .execute('AgregarUsuario')
      res.redirect('/apirest/Usuarios');
      } else {
           res.json(isValid)
      }    

    });
```

Comment: Hago las pruebas con postman estos son los datos que ingrese {
 "Name": , 
 "Age":17, 
       "Adress":"Los Alamos 232-12",
 "Phone":552685206,
}

Comment: a simple vista lo que veo mal es en la parte de Name que no tiene nada despues. Debería tener al menos un empty string ```''``` o un ```nul```l.    Puede ser que la última "," que esta después del numero de Phone  también cause cierto conflicto.

Comment: Ya lo revise es verdad al ponerle ' ' al Name me arrojo {
    "error": "message"
} en lugar de Unexpected token pero ¿Como puedo hacer para que me aparezca en postman que el dato es requerido ? y no solo en la consola

Comment: Para eso ya tendrias que hacer un res.send(data) depende también de la versión de node que uses tambien podrias usar res.json(data)

Comment: Si lo pongo en la ruta me dice que data no esta definido,  se pone en el esquema?

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, con la posible solucion, Espero te sirva o te de una idea de como terminarlo.